# Is it necessary to save singletons?

Tags: android, singleton, lifecycle

*Problem:*

I'm saving some data in a singleton class... Sometimes it happens, that this singleton returns null data, from which I derive, that it was destroyed...

*My idea/thoughts:*

Actually, I thought, the singleton will live as long as the application lives and as long as the application remembers anything else like fragments state for example, my singleton will exist with it's last data too. Isn't this correct?

**concrete problem:**

My case is following: I go from my main fragment to a sub fragment and save an selected object in my singleton... I stop using my app and come back after some time. My app remembers it's state and recreates the fragments, my fragment want to get the selected object from my singleton and get's null.

I thought, a singleton should exist as long as the application exists and therefore needs no saving... Whenever the application is ended, nothing will be restored anyway and my app won't remember anything, so that's ok anyway. Is that a wrong assumption?

I need an answer to this question, because if I'm sure, that above thoughts are correct, I at least know, that I have to search for the problem somewhere else...

Comment: if you need something stored it the application exists then try using `Shared Preferences`

Comment: I know how to save data persistantly, BUT I don't want to save the data persistently... Actually, I just need an answer to my thoughts... If a singleton class exists as long as the application exists AND if after the application is destroyed, all fragment states and other saved data is gone and the app will be cleanly startet the next time...

Comment: @prom85 : A singleton exists for as long as something holds a reference to it. After that it is free to be garbage collected.

Comment: Extend `Application`.  By definition, an application life time singleton.

Comment: ok, that makes sense... So if my app is in the background (and activities and fragments are destroyed, but the application is still existing) and my singleton is not referenced from my application class, it can happen, that it is garbage collected and could lose it's data like that. Is that the correct interpretation?

Comment: @prom85 : Yes, that's pretty much it. The last thing to be killed is the application itself. Even if you don't extend the `Application` class the default application framework will be retained until resources are low and the Android system destroys the process if it needs to. When all app components that hold a reference to your singleton are destroyed however, then it is free to be garbage collected. Unless your app restarts and calls `getInstance` on the singleton fairly soon after, you're basically starting afresh.

Comment: ok, thanks for making that more clear to me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a short summury of what I've found out (or have had forgotten)

- Activitys can be recreated, although the application was destroyed
- Singletons can be garbage collected if not referenzed from somewhere

So you HAVE TO SAVE your singletons! Otherwise, whenever your phone is on low memory, it may kill the application and create a NEW application, but RECREATE the activities...

For me, as I'm actually always use a single activity with fragments, it is easy to solve the problem:

- when I create an activity, I call a static restore function (BEFORE calling get!!!)
- in the onSaveInstanceState of the activity a always save the singleton to the bundle

=> so my singleton looks like following (base structure)

```
public class DataCache implements Parcelable
{
    private static final String TAG = DataCache.class.getName();
    private static DataCache mCache = null;

    public static synchronized final DataCache get()
    {
        if (mCache == null)
            mCache = new DataCache();
        return mCache;
    }

    private DataCache()
    {
        // init...
    }

    public void save(Bundle outState)
    {
        outState.putParcelable(TAG, this);
    }

    public static void restore(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(TAG))
        {
            // only restore, if necessary, i.e. if application was destroyed but activity saved our last cache
            if (mCache == null)
                mCache = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(TAG);
        }
    }
}
```